# Почему остаются правки кода при переключении между ветками в IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Скачал проект с GitHab, создал новую ветку, внес изменения, переключаюсь назад в ветку master, а там присутствуют все мои изменения. Зачем IDEA так делает? Или есть какие-то настройки, что бы это исправить?

Comment: для таких целей существуют stash/unstash в гите и shelve/unshelve в idea

Comment: А ты их закоммитил?

Comment: "Зачем IDEA так делает?" - надо перестать пользоваться тогда IDE как редактором, изучить свои инструменты и наслаждаться

Comment: Alexey Ten, да закоммитил

Comment: Когда слишком умные программы начинают думать о пользователе больше, чем стоит, такие программы подлежат удалению. С консольным Git никогда такого не было.